# Why my action methods are running synchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to understand async methods in ASP.NET MVC. Then I have created simple controller that in my opinion should work asynchronously.
But when I run `/` action in 3 tabs "at the same time" I get responses after 15, 30 and 45 seconds. Shouldn't be like, say's 15, 17, 19 seconds?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        await AsynchMethod();
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        await AsynchMethod();
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        await AsynchMethod();
        return View();
    }

    private Task AsynchMethod()
    {
        return Task.Delay(15000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have other tabs open to the same host (localhost) (at the time you ran those tests)?

Comment: Thanks for the engagement... I think I have resolved my confusions. Answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

After small change in code and another tests I noticed that my watch observations wasn't accurate enough:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        await AsynchMethod();
        ViewBag.Title += "  -  " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        return View();
    }
```

First and second request looks like called synchronously but the third not:

[image]

Comment: You should edit your question to add that, not post it as an answer.